# mod_rewrite.so is missing under /etc/httpd/modules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, centos, centos6

I was trying to use mod_rewrite but without success.
I searched online and found some articled but didn't solve my problem.
I finally realised that this article must solve my problem http://www.ewhathow.com/2013/09/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite-on-apache/
but the file mod_rewrite.so is missing under my system.
I have to note that i am using Centos 6 64BIT
.Is there  any way to solve this ?
I tried my self to install xampp on an other computer go to modules folder and copy the mod_rewrite.so file and copy it on my server .After that i added
 this

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

on `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
But after restarting apache…apache couldn't start…so i deleted again the line and apache restarted successfully.
I want to make mod_rewrite works on my server.Any help ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am using Apache on CentOS 6.5 installed from the installation CD and it does have `/etc/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so` file.  If this file is missing, I think you would be compiling your own Apache.  In this case, you need to modify the `SPEC` file for apache and add `--enable-rewrite` to the `configure` line in the `%setup` section:

`SPEC` file `%setup` section:

```
%setup
./configure --prefix=%apache_dir --enable-rewrite
```

Build apache again and install the RPM and the `mod_rewrite.so` should be in the modules folder after it finished installing.

Options and modules available to compile on Apache:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/configure.html

The other thing you could probably do would be to install Apache using `yum install httpd` on a test system and grab the `mod_rewrite.so` file from the installation, save and copy to the `modules` folder on the system you're trying to get working.  This would be my last resort method..

Without more information on what you have installed:

```
rpm -qi httpd
```

it hard to tell what would work best for your situation.